# How to prevent user from making radio button selection for each case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a form that contains 2 quiz questions with radio buttons.

For example:

Question 1: What is the capital of the U.S.?
1) NY
2) DC
3) LA
4) SF

Question 2: Who is the current president of the U.S.
1) Bush
2) Clinton
3) Washington
4) Obama

I enabled a javascript that prevents the user from changing their selection once an answer has been selected. For example, if I select LA for question 1, it gets locked and I can't change to SF.

The problem is that the javascript causes the same behavior for question 2, so I am unable to select any of the answers in question 2.

This is the script that I'm using:

```
      // prevent the user from making another selection once one radio option has been selected
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){ $('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled',true); });
```

Any idea on how I can set this script to apply per question and not to all the radio buttons of unanswered questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `name` value from the current radio being clicked, then disable that specific group:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() { 
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $("input[name=" + name + "]").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

All radio buttons for a question should have the same name. So add the name to your selector.

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){ $('input[type=radio][name='+$(this).attr('name')+']').prop('disabled',true); });
```

Answer (score 2):

So let's say you have a form like this:

```
<form name='questions'>
<input name='q1' type='radio' value='a' >a<br />
<input name='q1' type='radio' value='b' >b<br />
<input name='q1' type='radio' value='c' >c<br />
<br />    
<input name='q2' type='radio' value='1' >1<br />
<input name='q2' type='radio' value='2' >2<br />
<input name='q2' type='radio' value='3' >3<br />
</form>
```

Then use this script to achieve what you want:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () { 
    $('input[name='+this.name+']').prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){ 
    $('input[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').prop('disabled',true); 
});
```

Using `$('input[type=radio]')` inside your click function will refer to all radio buttons where you want to instead use `$(this)` to refer to the one being clicked on. Specifically `$(this).attr('name')` to grab the radio buttons in the same group.

Comment: "The problem is that the javascript causes the same behavior for question 2, so I am unable to select any of the answers in question 2." This won't solve the main issue the OP is having.

Comment: Close! He needs the question group disabled not just that individual radio

Comment: He doesn't want to disable the one being clicked on. He wants to disable it and other options for the same question.